# Disable / Enable button when the text and textarea are empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I have this code that disable the button when the text is empty, but I have a textarea html code. How can I include this that when the text and textarea are both empty the button will be disabled and when both are filled it enables. I tried the code below and it works on text only. Any ideas?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true);
    
    $('input[type="text"]').on('keyup',function() {
        if($(this).val() != '') {
            $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="textField" />
<textarea rows="4" cols="30" ></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="next" />
```

Comment: you have missed the textarea selector in jquery.... so it's not workin.....?

Comment: That's my problem I need to check also the textarea if it is fill in before the button gets enabled.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You miss the `textarea` selector in jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true);
    
    $('input[type="text"],textarea').on('keyup',function() {
        var textarea_value = $("#texta").val();
        var text_value = $('input[name="textField"]').val();
        
        if(textarea_value != '' && text_value != '') {
            $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="textField" /><br>
<textarea rows="4" cols="30" id="texta"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="next" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using the [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method like:

```
// Cache the elements first
var $text = $('input[type="text"]');
var $textarea = $('textarea');
var $submit = $('input[type="submit"]');

// Set the onkeyup events
$submit.prop('disabled', true);
$text.on('keyup', checkStatus);
$textarea.on('keyup', checkStatus);

// Set the event handler
function checkStatus() {
    var status = ($.trim($text.val()) === '' || $.trim($textarea.val()) === '');
    $submit.prop('disabled', status);
}
```

---

**F.Y.I.**

As mentioned in the [`.prop() API Documentation`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#entry-longdesc):

> **Before jQuery 1.6**, the `.attr()` method sometimes took property values
>   into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause
>   inconsistent behavior. **As of jQuery 1.6**, the `.prop()` method provides a
>   way to explicitly retrieve property values, while `.attr()` retrieves
>   attributes.

---

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/XcLAK/1/)

Answer (score 0):

use prop

```
$('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
$('input[type="text"],textarea ').on('keyup',function() {
    if($(this).val()) {
        $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled' , false);
    }else{
        $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled' , true);
    }
});
```

by attr we can do by

```
 $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('input[type="text"],textarea ').on('keyup',function() {
        if($(this).val()) {
            $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
        }else{
            $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
        }
    });
```

see [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: It doesn't work. I want that when both the text and textarea are filled in that's the time the button will be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Just check both input feild and textarea.
For that you can bind the both fields to keyup event and check the value

```
$('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
$("#yourtextfield,#yourtextarea").on("keyup","#parentdiv",function(){
if($("#yourtextfield").val() == '' || $("#yourtextarea").val() == ''){
   $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled' , true);
   }
else{
   $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled' , false);
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to check space.

```
$("textarea").on('mouseout', function(){
  if (!$.trim($("textarea").val())) {
    alert("empty");
 }
});
```

test it : http://jsfiddle.net/mehmetakifalp/ef5T9/

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="textField" />
<textarea rows="4" cols="30" id="texta"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="next" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true);
        $('input[type="text"],textarea').on('keyup',function() {
        var textarea_value = $("#texta").val();
        var text_value = $('input[name="textField"]').val();

        if(textarea_value != '' && text_value != '') {
            $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled' , false);
        }else{
            $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled' , true);
        }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer does the job but it is not enough. A text area and text field filled with spaces ( pressing the space bar several times) will enable the submit button.

You therefore need to apply `$.trim()` to the values from these fields before passing them to the if statement as shown below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true);

$('input[type="text"],textarea').on('keyup',function() {
    var textarea_value = $.trim($("#texta").val());
    var text_value = $.trim($('input[name="textField"]').val());

    if(textarea_value != '' && text_value != '') {
        $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true);
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed a solution where there are 2 text fields and a Submit button. The business logic was that the user should type in a value in any one of the text fields at a minimum to  enable the Submit button.

Here is my solution which I used in my code. It is not the best/optimal solution possibly but it did the job. Do comment if you have a better way.

```
//Enable Submit button for search only on text input

$(".inputFieldCSSClass").on('keyup', function(){
     var isEmpty = !($.trim($("#inputText1").val()).length > 0 || 
                     $.trim($("#inputText2").val()).length > 0);
      $("#btnSubmit").prop('disabled', isEmpty);
 });
```